# How multiple label this code

Tags: html, angularjs

I have this code that I found from the internet:

How do I use it from a controller and `ng-repeat` aside this directive?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

module = angular.module('treeGrid', []);

module.directive('treeGrid', [
 '$timeout', function ($timeout) {
 return {
    restrict: 'E',
    //templateUrl:'tree-grid-template.html',
    template: "<div class=\"row\"> " +
      "<div class=\"row\">" +
      "<table class=\"table table-bordered table-striped tree-grid\">" +
      "<thead class=\"text-primary\">" +

      "<th ></th>" +
      "<th >سطح</th>" +
      "<th>وزن</th>" +
      "<th >هدف</th>" +
      "<th>امتیاز</th>" +
      "<th>درصد تحقق</th>" +
      "<th>توضیحات</th>" +

      "</thead>" +
      "<tbody>" +
      "<tr ng-repeat=\"row in tree_rows | filter:{visible:true} track by row.branch.uid\" ng-class=\"'level-' + {{ row.level }} + (row.branch.selected ? ' active':'')\" class=\"tree-grid-row\" >" +
      "<td style=\"width:85px\" class=\"text-primary\">" +
      "<a ng-click=\"user_clicks_branch(row.branch)\">" +
      "<i ng-class=\"row.tree_icon\" ng-click=\"row.branch.expanded = !row.branch.expanded\" class=\"indented tree-icon\">" +
      "</i>" +
      "</a>" +
      "<span class=\"indented tree-label\" >" +
      "{{row.branch[expandingProperty]}}" +
      "</span>" +
      "</td>" +
      "<td  " +
        "<label >" + "<label >" +
      "خود ارزیابی</label>" +"</br>"+
      "تایید اولیه" +
      "</label>" +
      "<br/>" +
      "<label >" +
      "تایید نهایی</label>" +"</br>"+

      "</td>" +

      "<td > "+
      " <label type=text >1</label> " +
      "<br/>  " +
      "  <label type=text >2</label>" +
      "<br/>  " +
      "  <label type=text >3</label>" +
      "</td> " +
      " <td > " +
      "    <label type=text >4</label> " +
      " <br/>  " +
      "  <label type=text >5</label>" +
      " <br/>  " +
      "  <label type=text >6</label>" +
      "</td> " +
      " <td  ><label type=text >7</label>  " +

      " <br/>  " +
      "  <label type=text >8</label>" +
      " <br/>  " +
      "  <label type=text >9</label>" +
      "</td> " +
      "<td  >    <label type=text>10</label>    <br/> " +
      "   <label type=text >11</label>" +
      " <br/>  " +
      "  <label type=text >12</label>" +
      "</td>" +
      "<td >" +

      "<label type=text >13</label>  " +

      " <br/>  " +
      "  <label type=text >14</label>" +
      " <br/>  " +
      "  <label type=text >15</label>" +

      "</td>" +

      "</tr>" +
      "</tbody></table></div></div>",

    replace: true,
    scope: {
    treeData: '=',
    colDefs: '=',
    colDefs2: '=',
    expandOn: '=',
    onSelect: '&',
    initialSelection: '@',
    treeControl: '=',
    ////////88888888888888

    Weight: '=',
    Goal: '=',
    Operation: '=',
    Score: '=',
    PRealization: '=',
    Description:'='

    },
...
}).call(this);
```

Comment: have you tried to define the directive and repeat it? something like `<tree-grid ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items"></tree-grid>`? Does it work? If not, what doesn't?

Comment: '<tree-grid ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items"></tree-grid>' work but i want read from json for each cell that is multiple.

Comment: How use another controller ?

Comment: I don't really undestand what you mean... You want to use a controller? That's fine! Or use a `link` function, that's even better. Checkout the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)